# internal error: cannot load AppArmor profile 'libvirt-

Tags: virtualization

I am receiving an error while starting up a newly created virtual machine in ubuntu 17.10 using Virtual machine Manager. It worked fine once but I shut it down and now can't get it to start, I get - Error starting domain: internal error: cannot load AppArmor profile 'libvirt-

Comment: Is your system fully updated? Have you run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`? Did both complete without warnings or error messages? And please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1032939/edit) to include the full error. It seems incomplete.

Comment: This could indicate a wrong apparmor profile being generated. You can check the UUID via `virsh dominfo` and then check for `/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/libvirt-<UUID>.files` if that looks sane.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 22.04 and I still have the issue. Good news : **no need to uninstall apparmor**. Only two quick steps are needed:

1. **set security_driver = "none"** in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf

```
# vim /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf

#       security_driver = [ "selinux", "apparmor" ]
#security_driver = "selinux"
security_driver = "none"
```

2. **restart libvirtd service**

```
# systemctl restart libvirtd
```

Comment: This "fixed" it for me. I wouldn't do this in production.

Answer (score 1):

I had to uninstall apparmor competely followed by a reinstall of apparmor to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the ISO image was on an mounted storage, so the solution was:

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.lib.libvirt.virt-aa-helper
```

added the entries for iso:

```
/media/DATA/Downloads/Distros/** r,
/{media,mnt,opt,srv}/** r
```

That's it. The error is gone.

Reference: [LibvirtApparmor - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibvirtApparmor)

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error message on Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 x64 when moving kvm virtual machines from an older 14.04.5 Ubuntu Server install. Reinstalling `apparmor` didn't do it for me.

It turned out that I was missing the package `libvirt-daemon-system`. After installing this package, the virtual machines booted with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, virsh 8.0.0), I was simply out of disk space due to a couple large log files from some running containers in /var/lib/docker/overlay2.  After cleaning this up, the VM running under Virtual Machine Manager (4.0.0) started with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing apparmor fixed it for me on Ubuntu 23.10

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge apparmor-utils apparmor-profiles apparmor-profiles-extra
$ sudo apt remove --purge apparmor
$ sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apparmor
$ sudo apt install apparmor apparmor-utils apparmor-profiles apparmor-profiles-extra
$ sudo apt remove --purge libvirt-daemon-system
$ sudo apt install libvirt-daemon-system
$ sudo systemctl restart libvirtd.service
$ sudo systemctl restart virtlogd.service
$ sudo systemctl restart virtlogd.socket
```